# How to ignore `other element will receive the click` and still click on the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. I am going to click on a web element that is covered by another one so I receive the error `other element will receive the click`. I do NOT want to use `Select` so how can I click on the web element that is covered? 
These are things that I have tried:

```
action.click(dropdown).build().perform();

action.moveToElement(dropdown).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

dropdown.click();
```

Also there is no need to use scroll as the element is on the page but just covered by something else.

Comment: You can use JavascriptExecutor

Comment: Don't try to click an element that is not visible. It will make you test pointless since a real user can not click it either. You should first uncover the element by moving over an element and by using an explicit waiter if required.

Comment: What you mean "covered by something else"? Element is actually visible, but another element receive the click?

Comment: @Andersson yes, that's the case

Comment: @user5623520, Could you tell me whether there is a modal window (something like http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Creating-Loading-Overlay-with-CSS3-Animations-waitMe.jpg) displayed while page loading is in process? `Selenium` could "see" and try to click your element, but modal window could intercept this click

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I would not do this as it could miss potential defects. Not sure why you want to perform a click on hidden element.

Comment: you have the right to disagree, but it doesn't give you the right to downvote another answer by revenge. It really reflects a lack of professionalism on your personality. It seems that you don't understand that `HTMLElement.click()` doesn't perform a click from a user point of view and that there's a reason this exception. In a testing context, this answer is at best a bad advice which has already many duplicates.

Comment: Even after mentioning that it is risky that & it is not right from end user perspective, why do you downvote?  I was really hesitating to answer this - but the OP asked for code sample, i entered this.

Comment: Calling `click()` is not "risky". It simply doesn't reproduce the behavior of a user. While it's ok when scraping some data, it's not when testing a website, which is the case here. If you wanted to simulate the `click` with `executeScript`, you'd first have to scroll the element into the view if not already, check that it is displayed with a positive size, not disabled and that the cursor is also not disabled by CSS.

Comment: Then you'd have to generate the mouseover, mousedown, mouseup and click events and probably some more depending on the device. Just calling `HTMLElement.click()` doesn't come close to a workaround for a test. This is the reason for my downvote. Don't take it personally, just respect it.

Comment: Thanks this was perfect for my use case (not testing related)